# list output in template

Tags: python, django

I want to print list in templates...

```
@login_required
def upload_view(request):
    template_var = {}
    settings = Tracks.objects.filter(album__exact=None).values_list('file', flat=True)
    for setting in settings:
        list_setting = setting.split("/", 4)
        print_setting = str(list_setting[4])
        template_var["trackfiles"] = print_setting
        pprint.pprint(template_var["trackfiles"])
    return render_to_response('tracks/test.html', template_var ,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And output of pprint console log is

```
Django version 1.7, using settings 'audiotube.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
'github-ninja.png'
'sisters.jpg'
'blackwhite.jpg'
'altAlgOdLaLnLAYmJZF6CP1vwJCioRq6cT_NvkinlaLtBBS.jpg'
[15/Sep/2014 04:47:10] "GET /app/upload-tracks HTTP/1.1" 500 178171
```

I want to print these output into page. I tried in html `{{ trackfiles }}` which print only one output ( the last .jpg ) but i need entire list come into template. then i tried

```
{% for tracks in trackfiles %}
{{ tracks }}
{% endfor %}
```

above code also not working, what i am missing here ?

Comment: The request got `500 - Internal Server` error response. You may want to fix that first.

Comment: @Rohan I update my question with view function. I don't know what cause 500 error

Comment: If you add DEBUG var in your app settings you would be able to view the error when invoking the url. There you can find a traceback of you error and maybe it is in your template

Comment: @xecgr i am not the expert to do quickly, Can you link me tutorial how to debug

Comment: add DEBUG=True in your settings.py , then you will get all tracebacks of the errors

Comment: it's already `debug=true` only..

Comment: Have you tried creating a list containing the items yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no ,, what you mean by items here ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why the simple list not displaying in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initiate a list object first. That have to be "print_settings" object in your function. So if you add `print_settings = list()` in top of the *upload_view()* function, and change line `print_setting = str(list_setting[4])` with `print_setting.append(str(list_setting[4]))` that's the way how you can have an iterable list.

```
@login_required
def upload_view(request):

    print_setting = []  # or list()

    template_var = {}
    settings = Tracks.objects.filter(album__exact=None).values_list('file', flat=True)
    for setting in settings:
        list_setting = setting.split("/", 4)

        print_setting.append(str(list_setting[4]))

        template_var["trackfiles"] = print_setting
        pprint.pprint(template_var["trackfiles"])
    return render_to_response('tracks/test.html', template_var, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You may need to read [about lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: oh .. i don't know , i want to declare array first then each for items comes and store into it.. thanks for your help , that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Code in your template is fine, problem is in python code. When you iterate over settings, each time you execute

```
template_var["trackfiles"] = print_setting
```

so you are overriding dictionary item 'trackfiles' every time with current value of 'print_setting', so in the end all you have there is latest value.

Comment: yes it's iterate over each time ..but for example i need to print only `github-ninja.png` in `u'uploads/2014/09/12/github-ninja.png'`. How can i achieve that ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer - I was saying that when you iterate you are overriding dictionary element each time, and since you want to print all of them, you have to add them, not override.

And getting only filename is easy, just split("/")[-1] ;)